# jQuery Hide and show elements with add remove class not working after applying uniform.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

After applying `uniform.js` the jQuery doesn't work.

The jQuery was like this. [The original](http://jsfiddle.net/hFFsk/).

Now the html code changed after applying the `uniform.js` but the jQuery is not working anymore. The uniform wrapper added wrappers to the checkbox maybe that's why is not working.

here is the new code: [New Code](http://jsfiddle.net/hFFsk/1/)

Comment: Please post your code here instead of just a link to it on another site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, previously, your checkbox and your UL were siblings, so .next() worked. Now, however your checkbox is wrapped up and further down in the tree. So this:

```
$selexcta(this).next('.child-list')...
```

won't find the next ul.

I might be missing something, but I'd suggest not using .next() to traverse the tree. Rather, when a checkbox is clicked, deselect all checked check boxes. Then go 'up' the tree from the checkbox to the nearest li using

```
$(this).closest('li')
```

Then down one to the nearest ul

```
$(this).closest('li').find('ul')
```

then you can make that visible:

```
$(this).closest('li').find('ul').slideToggle('fast').addClass('mm');
```

You should be able to get away without using the .method() function at all.

Hope that helps.